# Hide row in excel not working - pywin32

Tags: python, excel, vba, winapi, pywin32

I am writing a small program in python with pywin32 that manipulates some data in excel and I want to hide a row in order to obscure a label on one of my pivot tables.

According to MSDN the proper syntax is

> Worksheet.Rows ('Row#').EntireRow.Hidden = True

When I try this in my code nothing happens - no error, nor hidden row. I have tried every combination I can think of of ranges to try and feed it but it will not hide the row in the output files.

Anyone know of a solution to this or if it is not handled by pywin?

EDIT:

Upon further debugging, I am finding that when I immediately check, the row's Hidden value is True but when I reach the save point the row is no longer hidden (another print reveals Hidden = False)

Comment: I'm not familiar with python syntax, but in VBA you dont put quotes around the row number... Ex: `myWorksheet.Rows(10).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: Incidentally it is row 10 I need hidden! Spot on!

The Rows() method will take both either string or int in pywin

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with python syntax, but in VBA you dont put quotes around the row number... Ex: `myWorksheet.Rows(10).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that a cell merge later in my program was undoing the hidden row - despite the fact that the merged cells were not in the hidden row.